# How to re-format xts data in R more efficiently?

Tags: r, for-loop, xts

I have a xts object with series of moving average based on n period.

```
              3     5       8    10
2012-11-16 1.573333 1.598 1.61500 1.631
2012-11-19 1.543333 1.576 1.60125 1.617
2012-11-20 1.546667 1.562 1.58750 1.601
2012-11-21 1.523333 1.530 1.57000 1.583
```

I would like to reformat it to the following.

```
              ma     n
2012-11-16 1.573333  3
2012-11-16 1.598     5
2012-11-16 1.61500   8
2012-11-16 1.631     10
2012-11-19 1.543333  3
2012-11-19 1.576     5
2012-11-19 1.60125   8
2012-11-19 1.617     10
2012-11-20 1.546667  3
2012-11-20 1.562     5
2012-11-20 1.58750   8
2012-11-20 1.601     10
2012-11-21 1.523333  3
2012-11-21 1.530     5
2012-11-21 1.57000   8
2012-11-21 1.583     10
```

Currently, I am using a for loop, which I don't think is efficient enough in R.

```
> sma1
              3     5       8    10
2012-11-16 1.573333 1.598 1.61500 1.631
2012-11-19 1.543333 1.576 1.60125 1.617
2012-11-20 1.546667 1.562 1.58750 1.601
2012-11-21 1.523333 1.530 1.57000 1.583
>
> n <- c(3,5,8,10)
> count <- 0
> for(i in n) { 
+     tempsma <- cbind(rbind(sma1[,paste(i,sep="")]),paste(i,sep=""))
+     if (count == 0) {
+         sma2 <- tempsma 
+         count <- 1
+     } else {
+         sma2 <- rbind(sma2,tempsma)
+     }
+ }
> names(sma2) <- c("ma","n")
> sma2
                 ma  n
2012-11-16 1.573333  3
2012-11-16 1.598000  5
2012-11-16 1.615000  8
2012-11-16 1.631000 10
2012-11-19 1.543333  3
2012-11-19 1.576000  5
2012-11-19 1.601250  8
2012-11-19 1.617000 10
2012-11-20 1.546667  3
2012-11-20 1.562000  5
2012-11-20 1.587500  8
2012-11-20 1.601000 10
2012-11-21 1.523333  3
2012-11-21 1.530000  5
2012-11-21 1.570000  8
2012-11-21 1.583000 10
```

Since for loop in R is expensive, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to perform the same task.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that the result is a data frame, and no more an xts object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a solution using `stack`.

First I create a sample data:

```
> dat <- xts(data.frame(matrix(1:8,ncol=4)),Sys.time()+1:2)
> dat
                    X1 X2 X3 X4
2013-02-28 00:17:25  1  3  5  7
2013-02-28 00:17:26  2  4  6  8
```

Then , I put it in the long format using `stack`:

```
> data.frame(index(dat),stack(as.data.frame(coredata(dat))))
           index.dat. values ind
1 2013-02-28 00:17:25      1  X1
2 2013-02-28 00:17:26      2  X1
3 2013-02-28 00:17:25      3  X2
4 2013-02-28 00:17:26      4  X2
5 2013-02-28 00:17:25      5  X3
6 2013-02-28 00:17:26      6  X3
7 2013-02-28 00:17:25      7  X4
8 2013-02-28 00:17:26      8  X4
```

Comment: This works well with the fastest proc.time.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1839587 just I am curious , what is your data dimensions?

Comment: ~5000 xts, each xts has 4000 rows and 40 columns

Answer (score 2):

If it's ok for you to transform your data to a data frame, you can use the `melt` function of the `reshape2` package. First I use sample data as your data are not easily reproducible :

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- head(as.xts(sample_matrix),5)
sample.xts
#                Open     High      Low    Close
# 2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
# 2007-01-03 50.23050 50.42188 50.23050 50.39767
# 2007-01-04 50.42096 50.42096 50.26414 50.33236
# 2007-01-05 50.37347 50.37347 50.22103 50.33459
# 2007-01-06 50.24433 50.24433 50.11121 50.18112
```

Then you can do :

```
df <- data.frame(sample.xts)
df$id <- rownames(df)
melt(df, measure.vars=c("Open", "High","Low","Close"))
```

Which gives :

```
           id variable    value
1  2007-01-02     Open 50.03978
2  2007-01-03     Open 50.23050
3  2007-01-04     Open 50.42096
4  2007-01-05     Open 50.37347
5  2007-01-06     Open 50.24433
6  2007-01-02     High 50.11778
7  2007-01-03     High 50.42188
8  2007-01-04     High 50.42096
9  2007-01-05     High 50.37347
10 2007-01-06     High 50.24433
11 2007-01-02      Low 49.95041
12 2007-01-03      Low 50.23050
13 2007-01-04      Low 50.26414
14 2007-01-05      Low 50.22103
15 2007-01-06      Low 50.11121
16 2007-01-02    Close 50.11778
17 2007-01-03    Close 50.39767
18 2007-01-04    Close 50.33236
19 2007-01-05    Close 50.33459
20 2007-01-06    Close 50.18112
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> xts = read.csv("xts.csv",header=F)
> xts
          V1       V2    V3      V4    V5
1 11/16/2012 1.573333 1.598 1.61500 1.631
2 11/19/2012 1.543333 1.576 1.60125 1.617
3 11/20/2012 1.546667 1.562 1.58750 1.601
4 11/21/2012 1.523333 1.530 1.57000 1.583
> 
> col1 = rep(xts[,1],each=nrow(xts))
> n = rep(c(3,5,8,10),times=nrow(xts))
> sma1 = c()
> 
> for(i in 1:nrow(xts)){
+ sma1 = rbind(sma1,t(xts[i,-1]))
+ }
> 
> sma2 = data.frame(col1,sma1,n)
> sma2
         col1       X1  n
1  11/16/2012 1.573333  3
2  11/16/2012 1.598000  5
3  11/16/2012 1.615000  8
4  11/16/2012 1.631000 10
5  11/19/2012 1.543333  3
6  11/19/2012 1.576000  5
7  11/19/2012 1.601250  8
8  11/19/2012 1.617000 10
9  11/20/2012 1.546667  3
10 11/20/2012 1.562000  5
11 11/20/2012 1.587500  8
12 11/20/2012 1.601000 10
13 11/21/2012 1.523333  3
14 11/21/2012 1.530000  5
15 11/21/2012 1.570000  8
16 11/21/2012 1.583000 10
```

Comment: The Op is asking about times series xts (class of the package `xts`), not a data.frame named xts.